# Solving this system of differential equation with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I'm trying to solve this system of differential equation (the ones in yellow markers are just constants):

[image: This is the coupled differential equation for distributed-feedback dye lasers]

The initial conditions for this system are n(0) = NN, na(0) = Na, n'(0) = q(0) = 0, q'(0) = some_constants, na'(0) = Ip(0)×Some_other_constants (shown in my code below).

```
FWHM = 9;
sd = 2.355*FWHM;
\[Sigma]p = 1.15*10^-21; (* m^2 *)
\[Sigma]pa = 3.8*10^-21; (* m^2 *)
\[Sigma]e11 = 1.1*10^-20;  (* m^2 *)
\[Sigma]111 = 0.4*10^-20;  (* m^2 *)
\[Sigma]aa1 = 4.1*10^-20;  (* m^2 *)
\[Sigma]ea1 = 0.9*10^-20;  (* m^2 *)
\[Sigma]1a1 = 1.3*10^-20;  (* m^2 *)
\[Sigma]eaa = 3.05*10^-20;  (* m^2 *)
\[Sigma]1aa = 2.0*10^-20;  (* m^2 *)

NN = 9*10^27; (* m^-3 *)
Na = 1.08*10^26; (* m^-3 *)

c = 3*10^8; (* m/s*)
\[Eta] = 1.32;
\[CapitalOmega] = 5.2*10^-8;
\[CapitalOmega]a = 2.5*10^-6;
L = 0.003; (*m*)
V = 0.38;
\[Tau] = 4*10^-9 ;(*s*)
\[Tau]a = 4*10^-9; (*s*)

Ip [t] ==  2.5 E^(-(t - 8)^2/(2 sd))*10^28;
   
sol = NDSolve[{
    n'[t] == Ip[t] \[Sigma]p (NN - n[t]) - (\[Sigma]e11 c)/\[Eta] n[t] q[t] -
      n[t]/\[Tau], 
    q'[t] == ((\[Sigma]e11 - \[Sigma]111) c)/\[Eta] n[t] q[t] - 
      q[t]/\[Tau]c[t] + (\[CapitalOmega] n[t])/\[Tau] - 
      (\[Sigma]aa1 - c)/\[Eta] na[t]q[t] + (\[Sigma]ea1*c)/\[Eta] (Na - na[t]) q[t] - 
      (\[Sigma]aa1 c)/\[Eta] (Na - na[t]) q[t], 
    na'[t] == -Ip[t] \[Sigma]pa na[t] + (\[Sigma]ea1 c)/\[Eta] (Na - na[t]) q[t] + 
      (Na - na[t])/\[Tau]a - (\[Sigma]aa1 c)/\[Eta] na[t] q[t] + 
      (2 \[CapitalOmega]a)/(\[Tau]a L (\[Sigma]eaa - \[Sigma]1aa))*
       ((exp ((\[Sigma]eaa - \[Sigma]1aa) (Na - na[t]) L)) - 1)  , 
    \[Tau]c [t_] == (\[Eta] L^3)/(8 c \[Pi]^2) (n[t] (\[Sigma]e11 - \[Sigma]111) V)^2, 
    Ip [t_] ==  2.5 E^(-(t - 8)^2/(2 sd))*10^28, 

    n[0] == NN , q[0] == 0, na[0] == Na, 
    n'[0] == 0, q'[0] == (\[CapitalOmega] NN)/\[Tau], 
    na'[0] == -Ip[0] \[Sigma]pa Na, 
    \[Tau]c[0] == (\[Eta] L^3)/(8 c \[Pi]^2) (NN (\[Sigma]e11 - \[Sigma]111) V)^2},
   {n, q, na}, {t, 0, 17}];

Plot[Evaluate[{n[t], na[t], q[t], \[Tau][t]} /. s], {t, 0, 17}, 
 PlotPoints -> (t, 0, 1000)]
```

I've tried to write my code as shown above, however I got an error message

> NDSolve::idelay: Initial history needs to be specified for all variables for delay-differential equations.

I'm not familiar with this topic and I personally think that I am not intending to solve a 'delay' equation. Can anyone pointing out my mistakes? Thank you.

Comment: Please check your equation. What is `exp()`? It should be `Exp[]`. And should be `Ip [t_] =  2.5 E^(-(t - 8)^2/(2 sd))*10^28`

Comment: `\[Tau]c [t_]` needs to come outside of `NDSolve` and have correct function syntax. Same with `Ip [t]`. But even with all these fixes I'm still getting `The number of constraints 6 is not equal to the total differential order of the system plus the number of discrete variables 3` and that means there are still more errors in this.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed the `exp` that @cvgmt noted, pulled `τc` and `Ip` out of `NDSolve`, and got rid of the extra initial conditions.

```
τc[t] := (η L^3)/(8 c π^2) (n[t] (σe11 - σ111) V)^2;
Ip[t] := 2.5 E^(-(t - 8)^2/(2 sd))*10^28;

eqns = {n'[t] == Ip[t] σp (NN - n[t]) - (σe11 c)/η n[t] q[t] - n[t]/τ, 
q'[t] == ((σe11 - σ111) c)/η n[t] q[t] - q[t]/τc[t] + (Ω n[t])/τ
- (σaa1 - c)/η na[t] q[t] + (σea1*c)/η (Na - na[t]) q[t]
- (σaa1 c)/η (Na - na[t]) q[t], 
na'[t] == -Ip[t] σpa na[t] + (σea1 c)/η (Na - na[t]) q[t] + (Na - na[t])/τa
- (σaa1 c)/η na[t] q[t] + (2 Ωa)/(τa L (σeaa - σ1aa))*(Exp[(σeaa - σ1aa) (Na - na[t]) L] - 1)};

sol = NDSolve[{eqns, n[0] == NN, q[0] == 0, na[0] == Na}, {n, q, na}, {t, 0, 17}];
```

which results in

`` NDSolve::nderr -- Error test failure at t == 1.740427851496955`*^-8; unable to continue. ``

To get a hint why that might happen, I evaluated the time-derivatives at `t==0`:

```
eqns /. t -> 0 /. {n[0] -> NN, q[0] -> 0, na[0] -> Na}
(* {n'[0] == -2.25*10^36, q'[0] == 1.17*10^29, na'[0] == -2.26701*10^33} *)
```

Those are some absolutely huge numbers, so it's not surprising that `NDSolve` can't deal with this over a time range of `t==0` to `t==17`.  Are you sure those parameter values are correct?  (I guess if the variables are also of large magnitude, it might OK?)

ps. out of curiosity, what do the equations model?

Comment: Also, I just noticed that the fourth term in `q'[t]` should have `\[Sigma]aa1*c` not `\[Sigma]aa1- c`. Fixing that gets `NDSolve` to `t==1.9939`.  So go over your whole problem to look for other typos if the parameters are in fact correct.